# How do you call an edge that returns to the original vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

This should have been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer to this question:

How do you call an edge that returns to the original vertex?

So basically given some graph:

$G = (E, V)$

$E \subseteq \{\{x,y\} | x,y \in V\}$

I'm looking for a name for these guys:

$E_? \subseteq = \{\{x,y\} | x,y \in V\, x=y\}$

In university in Frankfurt we called them *Eigenkanten* (roughly *own-edge*) but it seems that this term is not used very widespread anyhow in German.

Comment: A *loop*.$\!\!$

Comment: It's called a 'loop' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)

Comment: "Loop" or sometimes "self loop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) in English.